# How to get roots of this 4th order polynomial given below?

Tags: polynomials, roots, quartics

The polynomial I'm looking to solve is

$a^4 - \alpha^4 a^2 -k^4 = 0$

The four roots of this polynomial are given as

$a=\pm \lambda_1$ (pair of real roots)

$a=\pm \lambda_2$ (pair of imaginary roots)

where

$\lambda_1=\sqrt{\frac{\alpha^2}{2}+\sqrt{k^4+\frac{\alpha^4}{4}}}$

$\lambda_2=\sqrt{-\frac{\alpha^2}{2}+\sqrt{k^4+\frac{\alpha^4}{4}}}$

To obtain the above solution, I substituted $a^2=D$ and this makes the equation quadratic. I obtained $D=\frac{\alpha^2}{2} \pm \sqrt{k^4+\frac{\alpha^4}{4}}$. No problem till here. But obtaining the solution for $a$ (as above) is confusing to me.

The four roots given above are correct as I checked with some substitution using the expressions obtained from MATLAB and the above. But I'm interested to know how to obtain it.

Any help on the step-by-step procedure from $D$ to $a$ will be highly appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I believe there is a typo somewhere. Otherwise, we have $a^2(1 - \alpha^4) = k^4 \implies a = \pm \frac{k^4}{1 - \alpha^4}$

Comment: Surely your first $a^2$ is $a^4$...

Comment: Sorry about that. Yes, it is a^4. I've edited it now.

Answer (score 1):

The biquadratic or quartic equation given in your problem statement is still wrong. The $\lambda$ values given are the four roots of
$$a^4-\alpha^2 a^2-k^4=0.$$

Assuming that the error is a typo, we continue as shown below.
You have obtain the two values of $D$ that satisfy the quadratic equation,
$$D^2-\alpha^2 D-k^4=0.$$

They are, as you have mentioned,
$$D_1=\dfrac{\alpha^2}{2}+\sqrt{k^4+\dfrac{\alpha^4}{4}}\space\space\qquad\text{and}$$
$$D_2=\dfrac{\alpha^2}{2}-\sqrt{k^4+\dfrac{\alpha^4}{4}}.\qquad\qquad$$

Not only the value of $k^4+\dfrac{\alpha^4}{4}$ is positive for all values of $\alpha$ and $k$, but also $ \dfrac{\alpha^4}{4} \le k^4+\dfrac{\alpha^4}{4}$. In other words,
$$\dfrac{\alpha^2}{4} \le \sqrt{k^4+\dfrac{\alpha^4}{4}}.$$

Because of this the value of $D_2$ is negative for all values of $\alpha$ and $k$.

We use $D_1$ to obtain the pair of real roots as,
$$a =\pm\sqrt{D_1}=\pm\sqrt{\dfrac{\alpha^2}{2}+\sqrt{k^4+\dfrac{\alpha^4}{4}}}.$$

They agree with the values given as $\lambda_1$.

When it comes to obtaining roots of $a$ using $D_2$, we have a bother, because $D_2$ is negative. Therefore, we express $D_2$ as
$$D_2=\left(-1\right)\left(-\dfrac{\alpha^2}{2}+\sqrt{k^4+\dfrac{\alpha^4}{4}}\right).$$

Now, we shall write,
$$a =\pm\sqrt{D_2}=\pm\sqrt{\left(-1\right)}\left(\sqrt{-\dfrac{\alpha^2}{2} +\sqrt{k^4+\dfrac{\alpha^4}{4}}}\right).$$

Here, $\sqrt{\left(-1\right)}$ indicates that these two roots are imaginary.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers. Highly appreciate it very much.